# How can I render a birthday field to display only Day and month

Tags: users

I am trying to render a birthday field to display only Day and month.

user's birthday is 07/21/1971

When I print:

```
<?php print render($user_profile['field_birthday']);
```

I get this: Wednesday, July 21, 1971

I added this to get only day and month:

```
<?php print date("F jS", mktime(0,0,0,$account->profile_birthday["month"],$account->profile_birthday["day"])); ?><br>
```

it gives me this:
November 30th

Any idea why?
Thanks for any help, RJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **/admin/config/regional/date-time/formats** and select Add format. You will be prompted to enter a format string. This is a php date() formatting string. If you enter "F j" (without the quotes" the date format will be the full month name and the date eg April 11. Refer to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for a full list of options.

Then go to **/admin/config/regional/date-time** and select Add date type. Call your new type 'Birthday' and select the date format you just created from the select list.

Under **/admin/config/people/accounts/display** select your field and configure the display to use the 'Birthday' format.

Comment: Thank you I am new at this. it has save hours for me. i do not know PHP. I could try to figure it out but it would be at a snails pace.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Date](http://www.drupal.org/project/date) module and configure a new display format in its configuration page as `F jS`. Then in your profile display mode settings use that format for the date field.

Comment: <?php print date("F jS", strtotime($user_profile['field_profile_birthday'])); ?>

Comment: now gives me January 1st

Comment: in the date field it is set to Date (ISO format) 07/21/1971

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Drupal question, but a PHP question:

```
print date("F jS", strtotime($user_profile['field_birthday']));
```

Make sure your system's date format is the same as your Drupal's date format though or you could end up getting mixed up months/days!  (american date format vs european)